# Not able to ssh into 2 Compute Nodes on HPE Cluster

Tags: linux, ssh, cluster, hpc

I recently added two new Compute Nodes on HPE CLuster , But surprisingly, I am Unable to ssh into the new Compute Nodes from the Head Node .
[Unable to SSH to new Compute Nodes][1]

```
(base) [root@hn001 ~]# su harender
[harender@hn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ ssh cn001
Warning: Permanently added 'cn001,10.218.96.91' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Wed Jul  6 15:34:24 2022 from hn001.iit
[harender@cn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ exit
logout
Connection to cn001 closed.
[harender@hn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ ssh cn002
Warning: Permanently added 'cn002,10.218.96.90' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Last login: Wed Jul  6 13:11:22 2022 from hn001.iit
[harender@cn002 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ exit
logout
Connection to cn002 closed.
[harender@hn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ ssh cn003
Warning: Permanently added 'cn003,10.218.96.95' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
harender@cn003's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
harender@cn003's password:
[harender@hn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$ ssh cn004
Warning: Permanently added 'cn004,10.218.96.96' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
harender@cn004's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
harender@cn004's password:
[harender@hn001 ~/14-project-HWIS-dynamics]
$
```

Secondly when I check the Home Directories on the Compute Node 1 on which we are able to SSH , We find these entries.

[Home Directory on Compute Node 001]

```
[root@cn001 home]# ls -l
total 60
drwx------ 18 admin    admin    4096 Jun  9 15:12 admin
drwxr-xr-x 20 akshay   student  4096 Jul  5 23:45 akshay
drwx------  6 atul     atul     4096 Mar  9  2021 atul
drwx------ 21 harender student  4096 Jul  4 08:24 harender
drwx------  6 hemant   Faculty  4096 Aug 11  2021 hemant
drwx------  2 root     root    16384 Jan 28  2021 lost+found
drwx------ 12 monika   student  4096 Jul  4 12:32 monika
drwx------ 18 navneet  student  4096 Jul  6 12:27 navneet
drwx------  6 pbs      pbs      4096 Mar  3  2021 pbs
drwx------ 20 rohan    student  4096 May 22 13:08 rohan
drwx------ 19 shobhna  student  4096 Jun 27 12:41 shobhna
drwxr-xr-x  2 root     root     4096 Mar 11  2021 temp
```

Now when I check the Compute Node 3 and 4 on which we are unable to ssh from Head Node , we find a weird entry of UID and GID in place of OwnerName and GroupName instead.

[Home directory on ComputeNode 003]

```
[root@cn003 log]# ls -la /home/
total 68
drwxr-xr-x  14 root  root   4096 Jul  6 12:27 .
dr-xr-xr-x. 22 root  root   4096 May 23 13:04 ..
drwx------  18 admin admin  4096 Jun  9 15:12 admin
drwxr-xr-x  20  1007  1005  4096 Jul  5 23:45 akshay
drwx------   6  1003  1004  4096 Mar  9  2021 atul
drwx------  21  1004  1005  4096 Jul  4 08:24 harender
drwx------   6  1010  1006  4096 Aug 11  2021 hemant
drwx------   2 root  root  16384 Jan 28  2021 lost+found
drwx------  12  1006  1005  4096 Jul  4 12:32 monika
drwx------  18  1009  1005  4096 Jul  6 15:10 navneet
drwx------   6  1002  1002  4096 Mar  3  2021 pbs
drwx------  20  1008  1005  4096 May 22 13:08 rohan
drwx------  19  1005  1005  4096 Jul  6 14:46 shobhna
drwxr-xr-x   2 root  root   4096 Mar 11  2021 temp
[root@cn003 log]#
```

This is what ssh -v cn003 threw when I tried to ssh with verbose.

```
[atul@hn001 root]$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
[atul@hn001 root]$ exit
exit
(base) [root@hn001 ~]# su atul
[atul@hn001 root]$ ssh -v cn003
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/atul/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to cn003 [10.218.96.95] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/atul/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to cn003:22 as 'atul'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256 need=64 dh_need=64
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:f7VqrIHzOBmUfewXGUgyzymd4auSxcrmCtGidMTBFD8
Warning: Permanently added 'cn003,10.218.96.95' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-keyex
debug1: No valid Key exchange context
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1003)
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: KEYRING:persistent:1003)
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/atul/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/atul/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/atul/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/atul/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
atul@cn003's password:
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
Permission denied, please try again.
atul@cn003's password:
```

Comment: What did HPE support say when you logged this case with them? Also 'HPE CLuster' doesn't really narrow down what actual products you're using, can you add more detail please.

Comment: Actually using OpenSource Software hence , We are unable to log a case , Can you check with the images that I shared , If you could understand the unusual behavior of the /home on the two nodes as listed above.

Comment: Check the sshd logs on the problematic servers, run ssh with verbose output.

Comment: And please, don't post screenshots of text you could copy&paste. Just copy&paste it. You are just making it harder to extract information.

Comment: Also, provide more information about the nodes. Are they using a central user directory, are the homes local or network mounted, etc.

Comment: Hi Gerald , 

/home is created on the HeadNode and is mounted on all the Compute Nodes ,

I just ran the ssh using verbose from the Head Node by switching to one of the users and here is the Debug for the same 


After Entering the Password , It says Permission Denied.

Comment: Moreover the /home is mounted to all the nodes via nfs .